# Google maps directions api json result decimal format for latitude and longitude differs on refresh

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Google Maps Directions API v3 to get routes and show them on a mobile app. The code works fine, but suddently I found that sometimes fails. I ended up seeing that the same api call returns different LAT and LON values on refresh or recall.

For instance, the results of this query:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.158212,1.104743&destination=41.081765,1.131603&region=es&sensor=false

Sometimes gives me the coordinate values as

```
"end_address" : "Carrer de Barcelona, 61-63, 43840 Salou, Tarragona, España",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 41.08180,
              "lng" : 1.131470
           },
```

and on refresh sometimes gives me this:

```
"end_address" : "Carrer de Barcelona, 61-63, 43840 Salou, Tarragona, España",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 4108.179590000001,
              "lng" : 113.147030
           },
```

My errors come from getting the values as 4108 instead of 41.08. I can workaround this in my code but would like to know if anyone can help me out to find the root cause and try to ensure I always get the proper json answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the API broke, looks like someone opened [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5470) in the issue tracker (and the change that cause the problem may have been reverted)